# Scraping based on "nested property"

Tags: css-selectors, scrapy

After having created a few different spiders I thought I could scrape practically anything, but I've hit a roadblock.

Given the following code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="tab-title">Homepage</div>
    <p>
        <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
         href="http://www.bitcoin.org">http://www.bitcoin.org
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

How would you go about selecting the link that is in within `<a ... </a>` based on the text within the `tab-title` div?

The reason that I require that condition is because there are several other links that fit this condition:

```
response.css('div.col-md-4 a::attr(href)').extract()
```

My best guess is the following:

```
response.css('div.col-md-4 div.tab-title:contains("Homepage") a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Any insights are appreciated! Thank you in advance.

**Note**: I am using Scrapy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this using XPath:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="tab-title" and contains(., "Homepage")]/..//a/@href')
```

Find a `div` with class `tab-title` which contains `Homepage` inside, then step up to the parent and look for `a` child on any level.

**EDIT**:
Using CSS, you should be able to do it like this:

```
response.css('div.tab-title:contains("Homepage") ~ * a::attr(href)')
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you "step up" using css selectors or is that functionality limited to XPath selectors?

Comment: Very nice, I was unaware of the `~` and `*` symbols for css selectors. If you don't mind would you briefly explain what they do with regards to this example?

Comment: Basically it says to select all elements preceded by `div` with class `tab-title` and containing *Homepage* string. Check out the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) at W3Schools.

Comment: I was referring to the symbols, but thank you regardless.